# Passing through variable example

Tags: r

Been trying to pass a variable through this function. Tried variety of options such as get, substitute, !! sys but can't get it to work. I am trying to automate the bold part.

```
z<-function(s){
  PF_odds<-glm_coef_Death2[,grepl(s, names(glm_coef_Death2))] %>% gather(key,Relativity) %>% 
    mutate(**B36_Frequency_Of_Premium_Collection** = gsub("\\.","-",substr(key, var_length, nchar(key))), exp_relativity = exp(Relativity))  
  
}
z('B36_Frequency_Of_Premium_Collection')
```

The error i keep getting is Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

I also have another situation where I also struggling to automate. How would I also automate the bold part below.

```
PFSummary_pre$**B36_Frequency_Of_Premium_Collection**
```

Comment: As viewed by the parser, `}` is arriving while the parser is probably expectin a `)`, as it has been carefully counting opening and closing `()`, and there must be at lease one missing. Count like a parser and you'll likely find where you might wish to have a `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function -

```
z<-function(s){
  PF_odds<-glm_coef_Death2[,grepl(s, names(glm_coef_Death2))] %>% 
    gather(key,Relativity) %>% 
    mutate(!!s := gsub("\\.","-",substr(key, var_length, nchar(key))), 
           exp_relativity = exp(Relativity))  
}

z('B36_Frequency_Of_Premium_Collection')
```

Although not related to your original question but `gather` has been retired in favour of `pivot_longer`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I ran your code but I have this error (Error: object 'PF_odds' not found.)  When I don't assign it to PF_odds, the loop runs. Would you know the cause?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Can you provide a reproducible example to test it?

Comment: Prob an easy fix but couldn't find what I am searching for exactly. THis is a similar example. data(mtcars)

rm(mtcars)
v<-function(a){
  mtcars
}

head(mtcars)

v<-function(a){
  PF_oddsz<-mtcars
}                             first case works because its not assigned but 2nd case doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand. Yes, you need to `return` the assigned value. If the data is not assigned it by default returns the last line in the function. `v<-function(a){ PF_oddsz<-mtcars;return(PF_oddsz) }` and then you can do `result <- v()`